# Hibernate Feasibility for Single table database

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I have to design a web application to retrieve data from a huge single table with 40 columns and several thousands of rows for select query and few rows/columns for updation.

Can you please suggest me that for faster performance, use of Hibernate is feasible or not as i only have single table and do not have any joins ?
Or should i use jdbc dao ?

database : sql server 2008
java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Hibernate right, there's no problem in fetching an arbitrarily large result set. Just avoid `from` queries (use `select ... from ...` queries) and use `ScrollableResults`. If you use plain JDBC, you'll be able to get started quicker because Hibernate needs to be configured first, you need to write the mapping file, etc. but later on it might pay off since the code you write will be much simpler. Hibernate is very good at taking the boilerplate out of client code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve several thousand records and pagination is not possible then It might be a performance issue. Because hibernate will create an object against everyone and store it in its persistence context. If you create too many objects, it uses up a lot of memory. For these type of operations JDBC is better. For similar discussion see [Hibernate performance issues using huge databases](http://www.coderanch.com/t/218235/ORM/java/Hibernate-performance-issues-huge-databases)